# Can a Canon 100-400 EF lens with damaged AF be repaired?

Tags: lens, canon, repair, equipment-damage

Canon 100-400 EF lens Autofocus is damaged due to shake during travel. 
I can focus Manually, but Auto Focus makes some noise and doesn't focus.
I guess, the motor is not functioning. Can this lens ever be fixed? Looking forward to hear similar experiences.

I haven't shown it as Canon repair center yet.

Comment: The best place to ask this question would be a factory authorized Canon Service Center.

Answer (score 3):

I have sent a canon EF-S 17-55 2.8 lens with similar focus problems for repair, repair was prompt and the lens was as good as new, it took about a week as I recall and cost £195 it got a General Service , Replace Parts as Described , Set up and recalibrate , Relubricate , Focus System , Check and clean

Answer (score 1):

How much time has passed since you bought the lens? How do you know it was damaged through shake? Is it noticeable externally? If it looks damaged on the outside you may forget your warranty. If not, activate the warranty and wait for a free repair.

I guess it's always repairable, since they can fully replace the lens' motor. It only depends how much you want to spend on repair (or buying a new one) :P

Comment: AF stopped working completely. Its out of warranty period too. It doesn't look damaged from outside, it stopped working after a bumpy ride on motorbike.